# Do dinosaurs need to be mate boosted to lay eggs

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

Recently Ark has had eggs added into the game for most dinosaurs, I have been lucky enough to come across some in the wild and my dodos have laid eggs. However some of my female dinosaurs do not seem to lay eggs at all.

I was wondering if they need to be paired as male & female in order for them to produce eggs? Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they do not need to be mate boosted to lay eggs.

IME it may help in the frequency they drop though. Our mate boosted dinos seem to lay more eggs than our non-boosted dinos (another thought - our boosted are: dodo/dilo/raptor...stego/rex/trike not boosted, so maybe smaller dinos just lay eggs more often).

You really need to keep an eye on your dinos for finding eggs. They don't last long on the ground (5min for dodo, 15ish for rex), some of the smaller eggs can partially clip (and be extra had to see).

Comment: I have noticed that the smaller ones do seem to drop them more frequently, I can also confirm that non mate boosted dino's drop eggs as I had 2 scorpions drop eggs that were female only. The drop rate seems to be very random as I have had dodos lay 3 eggs in 30 mins then not again for a very long time.

Comment: in a recent patch they have now set Mate Boosted Dinos to have a 2x drop rate for eggs

Comment: in another patch they have set dinosaurs to now require a mate in order to lay eggs